# Replace letters in String with their ASCII representation using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to replace all letters in a numeric String with their ASCII number using a regular expression?

e.g.

```
"12a345b6"
```

should become:

```
1297345986
```

**EDIT:
Thanks for the friendly and helpful reactions *irony off*. A simple "No it is not possible in the way you want" would have been enough for me. Instead of this I receive indoctrinations that make me regret to ever post this question. Instead of extending my knowledge I end up confused and frustrated.
Thanks again!**

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problem do you have?

Comment: Why regex? Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure whether regex can do this, but it should be simple enough with a simple iteration over the string.

Comment: regex is the most unsuitable solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is really no need to use regex here at any part of the problem. You simply need to fetch each character, and convert it to ASCII code, if it is an alphabet, else leave it as it is.
`StringBuilder` would be of good use here.

Here's what you need to do:

```
String str = "12a345b6";    
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
    builder.append(Character.isDigit(ch) ? ch : String.valueOf((int)ch));
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

---

Note that, using `String.valueOf` around the `int` typecast is neccessary to avoid the character `ch` to get promoted to `int`. This is as specified in [JLS - Section #15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are
>   convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
> - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the
>     promoted type of the second and third operands.

So, if you don't convert the `int` to `String`, then as per above statement, the 2nd argument - `ch` will be promoted to `int`, thus appending the *ASCII Code* for `1` instead of character `'1'` itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really looking for a regex based solution then this code should work for you:

```
String str = "12a345b6";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)([a-z])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
   m.appendReplacement(buf, "" + (int) m.group(1).charAt(0));
}
m.appendTail(buf);
System.out.printf("After: %s%n", buf);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
After: 1297345986
```

Comment: Not sure to vote up or down. The **usage** of regular expressions was for *finding* alphabet rather than *replacing* them.

Comment: @Prasanth: Yes that's what regex is doing. Replacement is to generate equivalent ascii code and that regex of course cannot handle.